# How to do this bleach bypass (if so) effect?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, landscape

I'm an amateur photographer who loves to take landscapes shots, preferring dark colors. Recently, I saw with this series of pictures on the Another Escape Instagram page:

[image: example image 1]
[image: example image 2]
[image: example image 3]

I don't know if the images use a bleach bypass effect, but I really want to know how to achieve this specific effect in my pictures (which are very similar in subject to these). I noticed this effect is very often used by photographers both on and off of Instagram, so I'm guessing it's not an Insta Filter.

How can I edit photos to add such an effect using Lightroom or Photoshop?

Comment: Related: [What kind of photo effect is this, where colors are a bit washed out, yet retains the crisp detail and the colors are almost pastel?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23322/15871) and [What standalone software has bleach bypass effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71728/15871) and [How do I get this “Washed out” effect for street photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12264/15871)

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom has a "bleach bypass" effect preset , or at least it did at one time (I haven't looked for it lately). That might be a good place for you to start.